# Angular 4 - Convert date string to object for each server entity

Tags: angular

What is the best way to implement a conversion from date string to date object for each service the request data from server?
Lets say I have a userService that fetch some users from database. each user implements this interface :

```js
export interface UserAccountInformation {
  id: string,
  email: string,
  companyName?: string,
  phoneNumber?: string,
  firstName?: string,
  lastName?: string,
  country?: string,
  zipCode?: string,
  creationDate: Date
}
```

But when receiving the user on the client the creationDate is a string and not an object. I know it can be changed from the service, but I wonder if there is a general solution for all services using maybe a regex on the request response?
Is this a good idea to use something like that?

Comment: `new Date(userAccountInformation.creationDate)`?

Comment: I'm looking for a general solution for all the objects that I receive from the server from all the different services. this was only an example.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43228574/angular2-mapping-of-nested-json-arrays-to-model) - I think it's a more general version of yours. The same problem as with `Date` you will experience with other custom classes.

Answer (score 1):

Possible 'clean' solution with RxJS:

```
export interface UserAccountInformation {
  id: string,
  email: string,
  companyName?: string,
  phoneNumber?: string,
  firstName?: string,
  lastName?: string,
  country?: string,
  zipCode?: string,
  creationDate: Date
}

const response: any = {
  id: '1',
  email: 'test@test.com',
  companyName?: 'companyname',
  phoneNumber?: '+000',
  firstName?: 'firstname',
  lastName?: 'lastname',
  country?: 'country',
  zipCode?: 'zipcode',
  creationDate: '2017-01-01'
}

// replace Rx.Observable.of with Angular HTTP this.get('urlToCall')
Rx.Observable.of(response)
.map((response: any) => {
    response.creationDate = new Date(response.creationDate)
    //cast to UserAccountInformation interface
    return <UserAccountInformation>response;
})
.subscribe((userAccountInformation: UserAccountInformation) => {
    console.log(userAccountInformation);
});

Output:
{id: "1", email: "test@test.com", companyName: "companyname", phoneNumber:                 "+000", firstName: "firstname", 
creationDate: Sun Jan 01 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)
…}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I'm looking for a general solution to support this problem in the app scope for each http request.